# How do I create a list control with Rich text in FLEX?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I am a FLEX newbie, trying to port a Javascript-based prototype into FLEX. One thing my original prototype had was an unordered list (ul) which had list items that had rich text inside it, i.e. I had a mix of differently styled and colored text and some images inside each item. I looked at the List control for FLEX and it only supports displaying a simple string and an icon. How would I go about making a rich text capable list control?

Answer (score 1):

No help yet? I founded it. It's called ItemRenderers http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_1.html

Much like the renders in Java Swing.